# How can I use the "Multi" stream to parse output from JPQL resultList() to send individual items to a topic instead of the entire list object

Tags: apache-kafka, java-11, quarkus

Trying to create a reactive method (using the @Outgoing annotation) that sends a list of events to a kafka topic

e.g.,

```
@Outgoing("kafkatopic01")
public Multi<List<Thing>> poll() {

    return Multi.createFrom()
            .ticks()
            .every(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .onOverflow().drop()
            .map(tick -> (List<Things>) ds.getData())
            [...]
```

The "ds.getData()"  - in the above example  - returns a list of events ("Thing"s) - from a JPQL namedquery - to send to a topic.

QUESTION:  How can I code the above...

```
"return Multi.createFrom()..."
```

...such that the returned list is *not* sent as a single object to the "@Outgoing" topic?

In other words, how can I modify the above  "Multi" stream such that the list of "Thing" events are sent individually, and not as a single object

kafka
quarkus 1.11.0.CR1
java 11

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this ".onItem().disjoint()" accomplishes what I'm looking for...

```
return Multi.createFrom()
        .ticks()
        .every(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .onOverflow().drop()
        .map(tick -> { 
            List<Thing> list =  (List<Thing>) polldata.get(time.get("datetime").atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));
            time.put("datetime", (list.size() == 0 ? time.get("datetime") : Instant.now()));
            return list;
        })
        .onItem()
        .<Thing>disjoint();
```